# Retrieve the content of a section via MediaWiki API

Tags: ajax, api, mediawiki

I have a MediaWiki page set up in my company's intranet. 
I would like to get the content of a section in a specific page using MediaWiki API (through AJAX).

I would like to refer to the section by its title like 'General' and refer to the page by its title as well, like 'Licenses'.

Is it possible somehow?

The only thing I could achieve is referring to the page by its title and refer to the section by a number like this:

`http://mywiki.local/wiki/api.php?format=xml&action=parse&prop=text&page=Licenses&section=1`

But let's say I create a new section before 'General' I would have to update all my AJAX URLs that queries this page. So this isn't good enough.

I couldn't find any working solution for this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by first retrieving `prop=sections` to get the list of sections and their numbers:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=parse&prop=sections&page=License

Then make your original request, with the section number you figured out based on the previous request.

Keep in mind that two different sections can have the same name.

Comment: This looks promising!! Thanks! I'll try to implement it. Get back to you soon.

Comment: There's also a small chance somebody will add, remove, or rename a section between when you send the `prop=section` and when you request the section. Much more likely on a Wikipedia current event or controversial page than on an local intranet wiki.